# Mysql query to store employee attendance by month

Tags: php, database, mysqli, mysql

How do I insert all employee attendance(Monthly once) in mysql database
Here is my db tables

```
att_employee_id | att_year | att_month | att_present_days | att_absent_days |   att_workingdays
```

```js
Date.prototype.daysInThisMonthOfThisYear=function() {
  return new Date(this.getFullYear(),this.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
}
var days_inmonth = new Date().daysInThisMonthOfThisYear();

$(document).ready(function() {
 $( ".absent_days" ).keyup(function() {
   var days = $(this).val();
   $(this).closest("tr").find(".present_days" ).val( days_inmonth - days ); 
  }) 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="emp_att" action="" method="post">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="head0" style="width:5%">S.No</th>
        <th class="head1" style="width:15%">Employee ID</th>
        <th class="head0 no-sort" style="width:15%">No.of days present</th>
        <th class="head1 no-sort" style="width:15%">No.of days absent</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>ETO0001</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="present_days" name="present_days" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="absent_days" class="absent_days" min="0" max="<?php echo date('t'); ?>" onChange="absentdays()" style="width:100%"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>ETO0002</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="present_days" name="present_days" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="absent_days" class="absent_days" min="0" max="<?php echo date('t'); ?>" onChange="absentdays()" style="width:100%"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>ETO0003</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="present_days" name="present_days" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="absent_days" class="absent_days" min="0" max="<?php echo date('t'); ?>" onChange="absentdays()" style="width:100%"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>ETO0004</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="present_days" name="present_days" value="" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="absent_days" class="absent_days" min="0" max="<?php echo date('t'); ?>" onChange="absentdays()" style="width:100%"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is my query to get all the employees

```
   <form name="emp_att" action="" method="post">
   <table>
   <thead>
   <tr>
    <th class="head0" style="width:5%">S.No</th>
    <th class="head1" style="width:15%">Employee ID</th>
    <th class="head0 no-sort" style="width:15%">No.of days present</th>
    <th class="head1 no-sort" style="width:15%">No.of days absent</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
        $allemp= mysqli_query($con,"select * from t_emp e");
          $all_emp = mysqli_num_rows($allemp);

        if ($all_emp > 0)
        {
         $i=1;
            while($all_emp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($allemp))
          {
                 echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td>".$i."<input type='hidden' name='serialno' value='".$i++."'></td>
                 <td> ".$all_emp["emp_id"]."</td>
                <td><input type='text' class='present_days' name='present_days' value=''></td>";
             echo "<td><input type='number' name='absent_days' class='absent_days' min='0' max= date('t') onChange='absentdays()' style='width:100%'></a></td>"; 
            echo "</tr>";
                 } 
          } 
        else 
        {
            echo "0 Results";
        }
        ?>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
```

Here I am getting all the n number of employees in the above form. when entered all employees "No.of days absent" and then hit on submit I am able to send only last record to the database.
Can any one help me to send all the employees attendance to database 
Here is my form submission query

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
 $serialno=$_post['serialno'];
 $employee_id=$_post['emp_id'];
 $att_year = date('Y'); 
 $att_month = date('m'); 
 for($i=1; $i<= $serialno;$i++)
 {
  $present_days=$_POST['present_days'];
  $absent_days=$_POST['absent_days'];
  }
  $query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO t_emp_attendance(att_employee_id,att_year,att_month,att_present_days,att_absent_days)values('$employee_id','$att_year','$att_month','$present_days','$absent_days')");
  }
 ?>
```

any suggestions will be appreciated, I need to store all the employees attendance to database

Comment: Check that name of input fields are created. It might be overwritten with the latest values. Send it as an array format like "absent_days[]" it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you spelling for `INSERT`. And also you have missed to pass the connection object for `inserting`

First parameter should be the connection object in `mysqli_*`

```
mysqli_query(connectionObject,your Query);

$query=mysqli_query("INSERT INTO t_emp_attendance(att_employee_id,att_year,att_month,att_present_days,att_absent_days)values('$employee_id','$att_year','$att_month','$present_days','$absent_days')");


for($i=1; $i<= $serialno;$i++)
{
   $present_days=$_POST['present_days'][$i];
   $absent_days=$_POST['absent_days'][$i];
   $query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO t_emp_attendance(att_employee_id,att_year,att_month,att_present_days,att_absent_days)values('$employee_id','$att_year','$att_month','$present_days','$absent_days')");
}
```

Your query should be inside the loop. And as suggested by parag, make text field names as arrays `[]`
Soomething like this,

```
<input type="text" class="present_days" name="present_days[]" value="">
                                                          ^ ^
```

You shud do for all the text boxes.

Comment: And what about last comma after `'$absent_days',`

Comment: yes he shud remove that, i have removed it, was about to add in answer

Comment: Sorry for that actually it's a copy mistake,
It's working fine in my system, But only problem is it storing only one (Last record)

Comment: check the answer, you have to change in view as well as php code. View is as suggested by parag. Php code i have given there.

Comment: Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Check that name of input fields are created. It might be overwritten with the latest values. Send it as an array format like "absent_days[]" it will solve your problem

Comment: I am new to PHP, can you please share a bit of code how to send those values in an arry[]

Comment: upvote from my side coz, i have added your answer in mine and even OP canot upvote:)